# Why autocomplete intellisense doesn't work when trying to write a word that is a part of some other word?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, intellisense

When you try to auto complete a word that contains the same part of it's prefix in it, such as (UpdateDate) and try to write: Date, the intellisense won't view the word UpdateDate, but will view words such as CreateDate, this is obvious that the reason is that the word UpdateDate contains (date) and (Date), how to solve this?

Comment: This won't help you, but I tried reproducing this in VS 2012 with your example, and on "Date" and "date" Intellisense shows both CreateDate and UpdateDate. Regardless of whether they are variables or methods.

Comment: @Lennart I found the same as you. Side note, if you type the initials of the word you want as PascalCase and hit tab, the word will be filled in e.g. Debug.WL => Debug.WriteLine; UD => UpdateDate.